# How on earth do I codesign in XCode 4?

Tags: xcode, ios, code-signing

Everything has changed in Xcode 4 from release 3.

But I can't believe that Apple has chosen to hide such a basic and necessary feature.

Some people say, go into Edit Scheme. But when I go into that there is nothing about code signing.

Help???

Comment: Is code signing conventionally written that way in the Xcode environment? If not, please add a little punctuation so that an incautious reader (like me!) won't read it like “co-design”…

Comment: Yes, it's "codesign". And yes, it's tough to read.

Comment: By `codesign` do you mean some sort of collaborative feature? Or do you mean `code sign`, meaning attach a certificate to your project?

Comment: On a lark, I went to Wikipedia and searched for "codesign".  No hits.  It asked "Did you mean [co-design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-Design)?", which I learned is _is a philosophy in the American pragmatist tradition, which argues that all people have different ideals and perspectives and that any design process needs to deal with this_.  I agree that some punctuation is needed to disambiguate the present question.

Comment: It frequently appears in Xcode as codesign. The title is accurate, if hard to read. Try Google instead of Wikipedia.

Comment: If "codesign" is googled in isolation, all of the hits are regarding co-design.   If one adds "XCode" into the mix, it's all over the map.  The one example that I found that actually came from XCode itself was an [error message](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1764318?start=0&tstart=0) that contains an [intercapped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercap#Variations_and_synonyms) instance and an instance of the phrase "code signing" separated by a space.   I'd say Apple's use falls on the side of disambiguation via a space or BumpyCaps.

Comment: My googling tells me there's also a binary named `codesign`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you codesigning for publishing on Apple Store? In theory, that's made automatically when you archive the project.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well anyway after racking my brains over this for a half hour, I just downgraded to the much easier Xcode 3, with which I am very familiar.

Answer (score 0):

Code signing is still configured in your target's build settings. Select your project in the navigation, select your target from the list of targets, select the "build settings" tab, set your code signing settings as in Xcode 3.